# Checking if an object is an instance of a specific datatype given by a user

Tags: java, class, types

I am struggling with checking if an object is an instance of a specific datatype, which is given by user input. For example:

```
Object a = new Object();
String userDataType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What kind of datatype do you want to check?");
if(Object a instanceof userDataType))  doStuff();
```

I tried reflections but I still don't manage to get behind this...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you created an object of type `Object`, so the code you've shown is meaningless - that's the only type it has. If you want to ask about *any* object, just tap into `obj.getClass().getName()`, while being aware that even something like "String" could be java.lang.String or some.other.package.String, so only a fully qualified type is meaningful.

Comment: How many options are there actually? Maybe you could write an enum of all available data types and make it selectable via combobox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try comparing with the `getSimpleName()` of the class of the object, which returns just the unqualified class name (without the package name).

```
Object o;
String userInput;
if (o.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `instanceof` keyword works by comparing it to an actual object type, not a string. For example:

```
Object a = getUseObject();
if( a instanceof String )  doStuff();  // if a is actually a String
else if (a instanceof double[]) doStuff();  // if a is actually an array of doubles
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to the datatypes you wish to check for, handle exceptions as required.